# Capture all key-presses in PyQt

Tags: python, events, pyqt, keyboard-events

I am trying to capture all of key pressed in my program

```
def keyPressEvent(self, event):

    event = event.key()

    if (event == QtCore.Qt.Key_Q):
        print ('Q!.')
```

That function works fine when i am trying to capture keys in my window. (in this case Q_Key)

But if the key was pressed in a Text Widget (for example in a: QListView, QlistWidget, QLineEdit, and so many more ) it don't work. The function prints nothing. I am doing something wrong...
What can i do to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to install an event-filter on the application object to get all key-press events:

```
class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        QApplication.instance().installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress:
            print('KeyPress: %s [%r]' % (event.key(), source))
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)
```